# Unable to Map Array of MongoDB Documents Returned from Backend into React Components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to get my front-end to call to the back-end for all the "blog posts" that are stored in my MongoDB database. At the moment there is only one document for testing.

On the backend I have this api endpoint:

```
app.get("/api/blogs", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Getting blog items...");
    try{
        const blogs = await blogActions.getBlogItems();
        res.status(200).json({blogs});
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

This calls to a separate JS file with this function:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const connection = async () => {
    try {
        const database = client.db('personalwebsite');
        const blogs = database.collection('blogs');

        return blogs;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const getBlogItems = async () => {
    const conn = await connection();
    try {
        return await conn.find({}).toArray();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Then in my React front-end I am trying to take the returned array and set it to an Array there in order to map over it and create a new BlogItem component for each blog returned from the database:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.tsx";
import BlogItem from "../components/BlogItem.tsx";
import '../styles/Blog.css';

export default function Blog () {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [token, setToken] = useState<string>('');
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(localStorage.getItem('token'));

        async function checkToken () {
            const response = await fetch('/api/token', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
              }
            });
            if (response.ok){
              const jsonResponse = await response.json();
              if (jsonResponse.delete){
                localStorage.clear();
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            } else {
              console.log("Failed to fetch status of the User Login Session.");
            }
        }

        async function checkIfAdmin () {
            const response = await fetch('/api/users/permissions', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
            if(response.ok) {
                const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                if (jsonResponse.role === 'admin') {
                    setIsAdmin(true);
                } else {
                    setIsAdmin(false);
                }
            }
        }

        async function getBlogItems () {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/blogs');
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log("Before setBlogs", data.blogs)
                if(data.blogs.length > 0) {
                    setBlogs(data.blogs);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    
        if (token) {
            checkToken().then(isValid => {
                if (!isValid) return;
                checkIfAdmin();
            });
        }
        
        getBlogItems();

    }, [])

    console.log("After setBlogs", blogs);

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <main className="main-content">
            <div className="blogs-container">
                {blogs.length > 0 ? (
                    blogs.map((blog) => (
                        <BlogItem
                            key={blog._id}
                            title={blog.title}
                            shortDesc={blog.shortDesc}
                            imgSrc={blog.imgSrc}
                            pubDate={blog.pubDate}
                        />
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                )}  
            </div>
            <div className="most-popular"></div>
          </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have tried quite a few different methods for trying to get this to work correctly. At first I thought it was just a problem with the data not being returned quickly enough but even after getting the code to wait for the data to be returned and getting the Array to set. I get an error that Objects are not valid as a React child.

This is meant to be an array of Objects so that I can access the properties of each object for the elements in the component but I cannot get it to work for the life of me. I spent awhile using ChatGPT to try and get some progress out of it but this seems to be a problem that requires human intervention instead.

Comment: console.log("Before setBlogs", data.blogs) Is this line printing any json like string? And then  ‘ setBlogs(data.blogs); ‘ here the data.blogs is string, or object or undefined? This has to be array as setBlogs expect array here. If data is json using parse you can convert json string to array.

Comment: It prints "Before setBlogs: Array [ {...} ]" Which is an array containing 1 Object which is the Object from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is annoying but the issue wasn't with the rest of my code but actually that the BlogItem component had the props wrapped only in parentheses.

Here is the component:

```
export default function BlogItem ({title, shortDesc, imgSrc, pubDate}) {
    return (
    <div className="blog-item">
        <img src={imgSrc} className="blog-image" />
        <h1 className="blog-title">{title === "" ? "Placeholder Title" : title }</h1>
        <p className="blog-short-desc">{shortDesc}</p>
        <p className="blog-date">{pubDate}</p>
    </div>
    );
}
```

The fix was that title, shortDesc, imgSrc, pubDate. All needed to be wrapped in Curly Braces. It now works :\